# Use WITH clause for storing temporary data: What is the equivalent syntax to Oracle, but in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

The syntax for storing temporary data in the WITH clause looks like this in Oracle:

```
with data (asset_id, x, y) as (
select 100, 10, 20 from dual union all
select 200, 30, 40 from dual union all
select 300, 50, 50 from dual)
select * from data

  ASSET_ID          X          Y
---------- ---------- ----------
       100         10         20
       200         30         40
       300         50         50
```

What would be the equivalent syntax in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite it is simpler to use `VALUES`:

```
with data (asset_id, x, y) as (
  VALUES
  (100, 10, 20),
  (200, 30, 40),
  (300, 50, 50)
)  
select * from data
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dd82a51ca28dc4db80b172f421f178cb).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the syntax is the same as Oracle, except we need to remove `from dual`:

```
with data (asset_id, x, y) as (
select 100, 10, 20 union all
select 200, 30, 40 union all
select 300, 50, 50 )
select * from data

  ASSET_ID          X          Y
---------- ---------- ----------
       100         10         20
       200         30         40
       300         50         50
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=ad36770163fb780fcc40a0ae14c4c052)